# How would I remove a field from my embed if a value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, discord.js, undefined

I am writing an embed that displays results for a Discord bot, currently if one of my values is undefined it would simply stay in the embed, but I would like to remove any undefined fields.

```js
const highScoreEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setcolour('#0099FF')
  .setTitle('High Scores')
  .addFields(
        { name: '15s Highscore:', value: `myFunction(12)` },
    )
};
```

if `myFunction(12)` output undefined it would simply leave the value as undefined - how would I remove the field so the embed only displays data from my function that is defined?

Any and all answers are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a simple `if` statement:

```js
const highScoreEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setcolour('#0099FF')
 .setTitle('High Scores');

if (myFunction(12))
 highScoreEmbed.addField('15s Highscore:', myFunction(12));
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake: The if statement will check if the returned value is [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). This means you have to be aware of the fact that values like `0`, `""`, `null` or `NaN` are considered Falsy, not just `undefined`. This knowledge could save you from a couple of hours of debugging. (Also please mark the answer as correct, when it helped you!)

Comment: Yep @Max I couldnt for 5 minutes, thank you very much for the info aswell